# Creating files in /tmp changes default group ownership? We are supposed to stop using /tmp?

Tags: filesystem

I just noticed:

> ~$ touch ~/home.txt
>   ~$ touch /tmp/tmp.txt
>   ~$ ls -l ~/home.txt
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdough  **staff**  0 Dec  2 15:09 /Users/jdough/home.txt
>   ~$ ls -l /tmp/tmp.txt
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdough  **wheel**  0 Dec  2 15:09 /tmp/tmp.txt

Is it unusual that OS X uses the file system to decide the group ownership? I'd expected all files created by a user to have `staff` as the group.

I've been tarring cds in `/tmp` and then putting them in cloud storage. Isn't that a classic use case for `/tmp`? As users, are we supposed to stop using `/tmp`? I don't want my group ownership messed with and tmp is now wired to unexpectedly change the group.

Of course, just using `$HOME/tmp` is fine. But, I'll be sad to stop using `/tmp`.

Comment: The group is set on creation so the important code is how did you create the files (But as the answer nots you should use $TMPDIR /tmp is shred between users and so can get clashes in permissions

Comment: This isn't unusual. Files inherit the group class from the directory in which they are created in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same experience when using /tmp but using $TMPDIR worked as expected:

```
$ touch "${TMPDIR}/tmp.txt"
$ ls -l "${TMPDIR}/tmp.txt"

-rw-r--r-- 1 luomat staff 0 Dec  3 08:46    /var/folders/8k/0bqq33mn439938qxp7j7c1fc0000gn/T//tmp.txt
```